# 'preferenceCategory' style background isn't working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles, android-5.0-lollipop

I used to use the following style to set my `preferenceCategory`.
But as it looks, the background color isn't applied when running on `Lollipop`.

```
<style name="Theme.Preference.Category" parent="@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_light</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
</style>
```

And I set it : `<item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/Theme.Preference.Category</item>` in my theme.

is the background attribute changed in `Lollipop` ?

Comment: Why are you using `listSeparatorTextViewStyle` instead of `preferenceCategoryStyle` to set the preference category style?

Comment: I guess I followed one of the answers here in stackOverflow, but even if I set the style to override `android:preferenceCategoryStyle` it isn't fixed (it even looks like all other attributes are also ignored)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way Preference is structured, you will need to create a layout with these properties and set the `android:layout` attribute in the style referenced by your themes's `android:preferenceCategoryStyle`.

The example code below is suitable for Material. You will need to find appropriate substitutes if you're targeting Holo or AppCompat.

res/values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/MyCategoryPreferenceStyle</item>
</style>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCategoryPreferenceStyle" parent="@android:style/Preference.Material.Category">
    ...
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/my_category_preference</item>
</style>
```

You will apply whatever attributes you need in the following layout. You could also continue to use a style and specify a `style` attribute on the `TextView` element, but just make sure you're using a valid parent style.

res/layout/my_category_preference.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dip"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingTop="16dip" />
```

Comment: I am using AppCompat library, this answer is working perfectly with one exception, I had to remove the following attribute from style: `parent="@style/Preference.Material.Category"` and other linked-style as it generates error.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you will need to find appropriate substitutes if you're targeting Holo or AppCompat. For example, `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: This works really nicely for the title text. I had to change a few `?`s to `@` since I'm on minApi 15, but it works! I just need to figure out how to remove the divider below the title.

Comment: I get error 
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Preference.Material.Category'.